# Ansible: exclude item(s) from lookup result

Tags: ansible

The following Ansible play:

```
- name: Fetch domains
  vars:
    domain_lines: "{{ lookup('file', domain_file).splitlines() }}"
    debug:
      msg: "Domains: {{ domain_lines }}"
```

reads and splits the lines from the following "domain_file":

```
test1.domain.tld
# test2.domain.tld
test3.domain.tld
test4.domain.tld
```

This works nicely. But now I'd like to skip/remove the lines starting with a hashtag. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [reject](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#reject). The play below

```
- set_fact:
    domain_selected: "{{ domain_lines|reject('regex', '^#(.*)$')|list }}"
- debug:
    var: domain_selected
```

gives

```
"domain_selected": [
    "test1.domain.tld", 
    "test3.domain.tld", 
    "test4.domain.tld"
]
```